# Как парсить массив json в 2 разных массива?

Tags: json, ios, swift

У меня есть массив json и мне нужно его парсить в 2 разных массива. Вот как он выглядит:

```
"United Arab Emirates" : "AED",
        "Afghanistan" : "AFN",
        "Albania" : "ALL",
        "Armenia" : "AMD",
        "Netherlands Antilles" : "ANG",
        "Angola" : "AOA",
        "Argentina" : "ARS",
        "Australia" : "AUD"
```

Могу ли я как-то его парсить чтобы у меня было только это значение "United Arab Emirates"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let dict = [
    "United Arab Emirates" : "AED",
    "Afghanistan" : "AFN",
    "Albania" : "ALL",
    "Armenia" : "AMD",
    "Netherlands Antilles" : "ANG",
    "Angola" : "AOA",
    "Argentina" : "ARS",
    "Australia" : "AUD"
]

var arrOfKeys = [String]()
var arrOfValues = [String]()

for (key,value) in dict {
    arrOfKeys.append(key)
    arrOfValues.append(value)
}

print(arrOfKeys)
//["United Arab Emirates", "Netherlands Antilles", "Australia", "Argentina", "Afghanistan", "Angola", "Armenia", "Albania"]
print(arrOfValues)
//["AED", "ANG", "AUD", "ARS", "AFN", "AOA", "AMD", "ALL"]
```

Либо функционально:

```
dict.forEach {
    arrOfKeys.append($0)
    arrOfValues.append($1)
}
```